# Thermodynamics: Solving the integral $\int^{t}_{0} \dfrac{dx}{dt}=\int^{t}_{0}0.48(10-x)^2$

Tags: integration

I am working through some examples in my thermodynamics textbook and I can't figure out how this problem arrives at the result it does after integrating. I initially assumed it was some type of u-substitution method they used but I was not able to arrive at the correct answer after attempting this over the last few hours.

The integral statement is below:

$$\int^{t}_{0} \dfrac{dx}{dt}=\int^{t}_{0}0.48(10-x)^2$$

And here is what they get as a result:

$$\dfrac{1}{10-x(t)}-\dfrac{1}{10}=0.48t$$

Comment: Rewrite in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). As it is your question is completely unreadable.

Comment: The question was rewritten using mathjax hopefully it is easier to read now

Comment: Do you have the $x$ value start and end?

Comment: Whats the title of the book ? Looks like a seaparable DE..where x start at zero.What is the line before the integral statement ?

Comment: @Isham the title of the book is chemical, biochemical, and engineering thermodynamics fifth edition by stanley I. Sandler. the example is 2.3-2 from this book https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Chemical%2C+Biochemical%2C+and+Engineering+Thermodynamics%2C+5th+Edition-p-9781119321286

the line before that statement is just plugging in the molar flow rate of N_CH3CHO = 10-X which eventually gives the statement dX/dt = 0.48(10-X)^2

Comment: Thank you I will check that in the book...But you know your equation is just a differential equation that is separable

Comment: Well I just checket the example in the book the author just separated both variable and the integrated both side like i did in my answer

Comment: so do I do u-substitution on the left-hand side to get a function in terms of X(t)?

Comment: X is a function of t because you have a t function on the RHS ...It's simply a first order differential equation and it's separable. You separate both variable then integrate ...The bounds are on the LHS  $x=0,x=x$ and on RHS $t=0 t=t$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int^{t}_{0}\frac{dx}{dt}=\int^{t}_{0}0.48(10-x)^2$$
Looks like the author wanted to write:
$$\int^{t}_{0}\frac{dx}{(10-x)^2dt}\color {red}{dt}=\int^{t}_{0}0.48\color {red}{dt}$$

I just checked that differential equation in the book. The author write:
$$ \frac {dx}{dt}=0.48(10-x)^2$$
This differential equation is separable of order one, so that :
$$ \frac {dx}{(10-x)^2}=0.48dt$$
Integrate :
$$\int^{x}_{x=0}\frac{dx}{(10-x)^2}=\int^{t}_{t=0}0.48{dt}$$
$$\bigg|\frac{1}{(10-x)}\bigg |^{x}_{x=0}=0.48{t}$$
$$\frac{1}{(10-x)}-\frac{1}{10}=0.48{t}$$
$${(10-x)}=\frac 1 {\frac{1}{10}+0.48{t}}$$
$$\boxed {x(t)=10-\frac 1 {0.1+0.48{t}}}$$
And that's the final answer provided in the book.

Comment: This solution is correct, I was trying to do the same thing and post it but since he did it before so I dont want to repeat the same thing. Nice one. :)

Comment: Thank you @Math_Is_Fun....